# Stack the same row in each layer of a 3D numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Hi is there a way to efficiently stack the same row in each layer of a 3D numpy array? I have an array like this:

```
 a = np.array([[["a111","a112","a113"],
                ["b","b","b"],
                ["c","c","c"],
                ["d","d","d"]],
               [["a211","a212","a213"],
                ["b","b","b"],
                ["c","c","c"],
                ["d","d","d"]],
              [["a311","a312","a313"],
                ["b","b","b"],
                ["c","c","c"],
                ["d","d","d"]],
             [["a411","a412","a413"],
                ["b","b","b"],
                ["c","c","c"],
                ["d","d","d"]]])
```

**and i want to get something like this:**

```
np.array([[["a111","a112","a113"],
                ["a211","a212","a213"],
                ["a311","a312","a313"],
                ["a411","a412","a413"]],
               [["b","b","b"],
                ["b","b","b"],
                ["b","b","b"],
                ["b","b","b"]],
               [["c","c","c"],
                ["c","c","c"],
                ["c","c","c"],
                ["c","c","c"]],
               [["d","d","d"],
                ["d","d","d"],
                ["d","d","d"],
                ["d","d","d"]]])
```

Right now I'm looping through the whole array and stacking it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html):

```
a.swapaxes(0,1)
```

output:

```
array([[['a111', 'a112', 'a113'],
        ['a211', 'a212', 'a213'],
        ['a311', 'a312', 'a313'],
        ['a411', 'a412', 'a413']],

       [['b', 'b', 'b'],
        ['b', 'b', 'b'],
        ['b', 'b', 'b'],
        ['b', 'b', 'b']],

       [['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c']],

       [['d', 'd', 'd'],
        ['d', 'd', 'd'],
        ['d', 'd', 'd'],
        ['d', 'd', 'd']]], dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: And here I was fiddling with `np.stack(np.split(a, 4, axis=1)).reshape(4, 4, 3)` LOL, of *course* there's a built-in method...

Comment: @ddejohn it's not always the case with numpy, there is a **lot of** methods, but for very simple things sometimes, surprisingly, not (e.g., like pandas' `shift` (not roll!), `groupby`, etc.) ;)